# Overlap of slivers

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver, flutter-sliverappbar

I have a problem with SliverPersistentHeaders. I have CustomScroll with CupertinoSliverNavigationBar and custom SliverPersistentHeader, with SearchTextField and button. My custom SliverPersistentHeader is floating. But when i scrolling back, it's staying behind the NavigationBar. What's wrong? How to implement this layout correctly?

This is initial state

[image: initstate]

This is overlap. My custom bar under the NavigationBar

[image: overlap]

My code here:

It's page layout

```
class GeneralBalancesScreenLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  const GeneralBalancesScreenLayout({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(slivers: [
      //----------------------------------------------------------------------
      //NavigationBar
      //----------------------------------------------------------------------
      const PlatformWidget(
        defaultWidget: SizedBox.shrink(),
        iosWidget: IosSliverNavigationBar(),
      ),

      const PlatformWidget(
          defaultWidget: SizedBox.shrink(), iosWidget: IosSearchBar()),

      SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (_, index) => const Center(child: Text("-----"))))
    ]);
  }
}
```

It's custom bar

```
class IosSearchBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const IosSearchBar({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SliverPersistentHeader(
      floating: true,
      delegate: GenericSliverHeader(
          maxExtend: 55,
          minExtend: 55,
          backgroundColor:
              CupertinoTheme.of(context).barBackgroundColor.withOpacity(1),
          body: Stack(
            fit: StackFit.expand,
            children: [
              Container(
                  color: CupertinoTheme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    const Expanded(
                        child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 0, 0, 0),
                      child: CupertinoSearchTextField(),
                    )),
                    CupertinoButton(
                        child: const Text('Добавить'), onPressed: () {})
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: May u elaborate, "But when i scrolling back, it's staying behind the NavigationBar. What's wrong?"

Comment: I mean, when i scroll CustomScrolView, my floating searchbar stay under NavigationBar. Pic 2 on my post

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoeSm.png

Comment: u defined maxExtend & minExtend to 55 but initially its more than dat. so when u r scrolling it gets bound to 55 soo ur search widget hides under it. try to expand ur maxExtend value

Comment: yes, i understand it. but in initial state (start point of CustomScrollView), search bar will be  with height = maxHeight. But i need 55 height =(

Comment: try this, body: SizedBox.expand(child: Stack() )

Comment: can you simplify the widget that will reproduce the same error,